# Are string indexers valid in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, internet-explorer-8, indexer

I ran into a bug that manifested itself in IE8, but not in Firefox, Chrome or IE9+.

A snippet of code:

```
Date.prototype.ddmmyyyy = function() {
    var yyyy = this.getFullYear().toString();
    var mm = (this.getMonth()+1).toString();
    var dd = this.getDate().toString();
    return (dd[1]?dd:"0"+dd[0]) + '/' + (mm[1]?mm:"0"+mm[0]) + '/' + yyyy;
};
```

I won't go into details explaining that it does (or tries to) which is blindingly obvious. I wasn't aware that `dd[0]` and `dd[1]` would both return *`undefined`* in IE8.

What's a better way to write the code?  Or is there a way to make the string [/array] indexer work?

Comment: +1 for *manifested itself*. I have used that phrase a lot myself. :-)

Comment: Note: It was some bit of code I picked up from an SO question. When I get time I'll hunt it down and burn the answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could modify your ternary statement to check the string's length.

`dd.length > 1 ? dd : '0' + dd`

Answer (score 4):

Use `.charAt(1)` instead of `[1]` notation.

---

Or you could `.split()` the strings into Arrays.

```
var dd = this.getDate().toString().split("");

dd[1];
```

---

Ultimately, I'd do it like this:

```
Date.prototype.ddmmyyyy = function() {
    var yyyy = this.getFullYear();
    var mm = ("0" + (this.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2);
    var dd = ("0" + this.getDate()).slice(-2);
    return dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy;
};
```

Comment: Does charAt return undefined, or will `('1'.charAt(1))[1]` return false?

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi: It will return an empty string, which will evaluate as a falsey value. So your conditional operators will still work.